# jquery for twitter profileImages output in list

Tags: jquery

I need some help re-writing my for statement so that one a href tag appears on first li two href tags on the second li, three href tags on the third li, etc. until the full length of items have been populated in full. I am trying to display twitter profile images in a christmas tree format (triangle).

**JavaScript**

```
var getJasonTweets = function(){
    $.getJSON('tweets.json', function(json, textStatus) {
        /*stuff to do after success */
        for (i=0; i<=json.statuses.length; i++){
            var status = json.statuses[i];
            var profileImages = nano("<a href='//twitter.com/statuses/{user.screenName}/{id}'><span class='tree-bauble'><img src='{user.profileImageUrl}' /></span></a>", status);
            // logic
            var li= $('li').append(profileImages);
            $("#twitter-tree").append(li);
        }
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="tree">
        <ul id="twitter-tree">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--tree-->
```

**SASS**

```
        .tree{
        position:relative;
        margin-top:-120px;
        width:100%;
        z-index:0;
        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            display: block;
            text-align:center;
            margin: 2% auto;
            padding:0;
            li{
                display: block;
                width:100%;
                a{
                    width: 5%;
                    height:0;
                    padding-bottom: 5%;
                    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
                    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    background: #4679BD; 
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-align: center;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    margin: 2% 1.5%;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.5);
                    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.5);
                    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.5);
                }
                a:nth-child(1){
                    clear:both;
                }
            }
            li:nth-child(n+1){
                margin-bottom:1%;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your HTML and CSS?

Comment: updated to include HTML and CSS, sorry

Comment: So is the format of the "tree" already present and fixed? You don't create it but only want to put the images into the  `li`s?

Comment: yes thats correct, i have built a static placeholder li tree in html and just want to replace the a hrefs

Comment: at the moments it outputs 50 items (coming from json) into each list item...

Comment: maybe i'm doing it incorrectly....i'm open to suggestions...

Comment: i have changed the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out - heres the amended code if your interested

```
var getJasonTweets = function(){
    $.getJSON('tweets.json', function(json, textStatus) {
        /*optional stuff to do after success */
        var limit = 1;
        var current = 0;
        var li= $('<li></li>');
        for (var i=0; i<json.statuses.length; i++){
            //replaces the normal with bigger
            $('.profileTweetImages').each(function () {
                var profileImage = $(this);
                profileImage.attr('src', profileImage.attr('src').replace('_normal', '_bigger'));
            });
            var status = json.statuses[i];
            var profileImages = nano("<a href='//twitter.com/status/{user.screenName}/{id}'><span class='tree-bauble'><img src='{user.profileImageUrl}' class='profileTweetImages' /></span></a>", status);
            // logic
            li.append(profileImages);
            current++;
            if (current == limit) {
                current = 0;
                limit++;
                $("#twitter-tree").append(li);
                li= $('<li></li>');
            }
        }
    });
};
```